# How to change content in iOS application?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm new to developing, and I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to change the content in my app without having to update the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to change anything other than the App Store meta-data (except keywords) on your app is to issue an update. You do not have to change anything to issue an update; it can be exactly the same. Alternately, you can change everything about the app (except the bundle id) when you issue an update.

Comment: Alright, do you know if there is a way i could change the text in the application in real time?

Comment: The only way to achieve this is to have the app gather data from a website that you maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You can download new content from the web, or include different "content sets" and make them switch according to your application logic.

Comment: Thanks thats what I was thinking would have to happen but i wasn't sure.

Answer (score 0):

Apple does this in their iTunes and App Store apps, albeit somewhat more subtly. When they rolled out the "purchased" tab (and, if I recall correctly, Ping) they were able to update the UI without issuing an update.

As others have mentioned, to accomplish this, you host your information online and your app can check for updates as necessary. (Either every launch, or whenever you feel it necessary.)